# Android In-app billing missed to mark revoke when refund

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

First of all, my situations are in test purchases. Not real purchases.

I made a test app for in-app billing. And added a Google ID for testing.

My purchase item is managed item(not-consumable). The purchase is working fine. But I have a problem with refunding.

[image]

If mark the revoke checkbox in the refunding dialog in Google Play Console, the Google removes the item from user properly. The order and product ID does not appear in the user's purchases information. It has no problem.

But, if **NOT** mark the revoke checkbox, the item still preserves in the user even though money has been refunded. It does not remove even though clear Google Play cache and user-data, re-login, re-boot.

Of course, you can say take care when refunding. However, what can I do if I occurred mistake forgetting to mark it? I cannot find any of **revoke** UI in the refunded order details page.

EDIT: [`Orders: refund`](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/orders/refund?hl=en) See the description of `revoke` parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must cancel the usage by marking the purchase as consumed using your server-side or using your application code. You can't remove it from Play Console anymore.

Find the documentation at https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_onetime

```
ConsumeResponseListener listener = new ConsumeResponseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onConsumeResponse(@BillingResponse int responseCode, String outToken) {
            if (responseCode != BillingResponse.OK) {
                // This user has got a refund, remove the feature here.
            }
    }
};
mBillingClient.consumeAsync(purchaseToken, listener);
```